# Help with an regular expression for date + 3 fixed character

Tags: regex

I have a url and I need to get rid of everything other than the code for the current date.

For example this is the link I have:

http://e-ditionsbyfry.com/Olive/ODE/WAC/Default.aspx?href=WAC/2011/03/01&pageno=18

The bit I need is:

WAC/2011/03/01

The 3 letters are always the same however the date will change eg:

WAC/2012/04/02

Can someone please help me with the regular expression needed to find this sequence?

Comment: In lieu of being someone's bestest friend forever, perhaps you would merely accept an answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
(WAC\/(?:19|20)\d\d\/(?:0[1-9]|1[012])\/(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I cant seem to get this to work. Any idea how i could use it for the stated task, in c# ???

Comment: got the answer. Thanks! Regex re = new Regex(@"WAC\/(?:19|20)\d\d\/(?:0[1-9]|1[012])\/(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])");
                Match m = re.Match(ViewState["magazineEdition"].ToString());

Answer (score 2):

This would work in Python (not tested):

```
r'WAC/[d]{4}/[d][d]/[d][d]'
```

To be safe, you could also search for the `href=` in front:

```
r'href=WAC/[d]{4}/[d][d]/[d][d]'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the part you want will always be the value to the key `href`, then

```
/\?.*?href=(WAC[^\&]+)/
```